# Why does magnification work?

Tags: optics, lenses, telescopes, microscopy

I have read the question [How do telescopes work as magnifiers?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516777/how-do-telescopes-work-as-magnifiers) but it doesn't quite address, as far as I can tell, my question.

I'm trying to wrap my head around **why** magnification works rather than **how** it works. Based on my understanding of the functioning of lens-based magnification, the three objects all function, essentially, the same way:

1. [image: List item]
2. [image: List item]
3. [image: List item]

I'm intentionally ignoring reflective mirror-based telescopes for simplicity. Sets of curved lenses refract light, thus collecting more light, to specific focal points creating virtual images where more details can be perceived. Though I'm not deeply versed on the formulas that describe this phenomena, I understand the basics.

What I'm grappling with is that magnification happens at all. Assuming my understanding is correct, this would mean that, standing on a high mountain on a clear night and looking up at the stars with the naked eye, the "information" that's available to our eyes is that same as the information available to an observatory telescope nearby.

I imagine the explanation is simple but I can't "fill in the gap" that makes such a dramatic difference in perceptible (not accessible) information  between the naked eye and the sky seen through the telescope. Why does "more light", which is fairly diffuse and coming from an extremely distant origin (another planet, for example), produce so much extra perceptible information?

If someone has answer, that would be amazing but I would be just as happy as being pointed to a good discussion of what's really happening.

Comment: A complete answer to this is quite complex if you go into all the details (e.g. the diffraction limit). But if you understand the how, the why it is possible is rather obvious.

For the case of the telescope there is one obvious reason: A telescope has a *large* aperture, so it can collect much more light than the eye with it's small pupil (and correspondingly resolve source of lower intensity). The large aperture also helps with radial resolution, which is limited by diffraction.

Comment: Re, "information that's available to our eyes is that same as the information available to an observatory telescope nearby." Not quite true. The telescope has a much larger _aperture._ That has two consequences; (1) vastly more light from the subject enters the telescope aperture than is able to enter the pupil of your eye. The telescope, therefore, can see objects that are far too faint for you to see with your naked eye. (2) Is the _diffraction limit._ TLDR: Light entering a larger aperture can be focused more sharply. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system)

Comment: Basically schematics of [magnifying lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens#/media/File:Lens3b.svg) in wiki says it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing about a telescope is not that the magnification has this value or that value, but that the aperture and the relevant optical components such as a mirror are *large*. This has two implications, and both are important:

1. in each second a lot more light enters a big telescope than enters your eye
2. the diffraction owing to the finite size of the aperture is less in a telescope than in your eye

By choosing the placement of the optical components, you can get any finite value of magnification. This means that two rays entering the telescope with some small angle between them can leave the telescope with a much larger angle between them. That is what magnification means. But no more light is coming out than went in. Therefore the output light is being spread out, and is correspondingly dimmer. So really what magnification offers you is a trade-off: you can have small magnification and a bright image, or large magnification and a dim image. But what we want is large magnification and a bright image, so our best bet is to increase the size of the telescope aperture.

That is one major difference between the human eye and a telescope, and it should answer your intuition about information.

The other important consideration is resolution and diffraction (item 2 in my list above). Diffraction results in an angle blur of the order of $\lambda/D$ for light of wavelength $\lambda$ passing through an aperature of diameter $D$. If you set the magnification very large (and remember, any value is easily obtained just by adjusting the distances between optical components) then all you succeed in doing is blowing up the blurry diffraction effects. You won't see any more detail that way. The best policy is to pick the magnification so that diffraction blur is matched to the size of your light-detecting elements (pixels in a CCD camera; rods and cones in your eye). We can go sub-diffraction limit, to some extent, by deconvolving the data so there is value in blowing up the diffraction blur so that it spreads over, say, a radius of 10 pixels or so, but there is not much to be gained by increasing the magnification beyond that.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer but please read it along with Lamda's above. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

The light carries the information just fine. But your eye can only distinguish and interpret this information down to certain resolution due to the size of the rods or photoreceptor cells in your retina.

Basically, if your visual sense is a screen then each pixel on this screen can only depict one colour. Showing an enormous image will thus requires trade-off's when several pieces of information is comes with the same pixel. The pixel can only show one and thus must choose a way to "blend" it together. Enlarging a smaller portion of the full picture, which is what a telescope does, spreads out the information bits our your visual "screen" allowing for the details to be spread out more, thus covering more pixels and thus becoming distinguishable.

Comment: This is only partially true, insofar that the eye is diffraction limited (and the resolution of the retina at the fovea is close to the refraction limit). So even if you had smaller photoreceptor cells, the resolution would still be limited by the point-spread of the optical system.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Good point, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you’re looking for an intuitive answer.
Imagine looking into a night sky. You will see almost half of the sky. If you try to focus on a small area you will be unsuccessful. Even if you close one eye. Squinting might help a little but not much. You have an extremely wide field of view.
Now next to you is a telescope. Unlike your eyes it will only focus the parallel rays of light that fall onto its surface. Compared to your eyes it’s field of view is much smaller.
When the telescope’s focused light passes the focal point it begins to spread out. If a lens is place in the spreading light’s path the rays will be refracted to parallel once again.
When you look through this lens your entire pupil will be fill with this parallel light. It will look big because it will fill your entire field of view.

Comment: I feel that this answer and Andrew Steane's (below) combined are the most complete answer in both responding to my intuitive struggle and providing clarification but Andrew's is more thorough so I must accept theirs as I can only accept one.

Answer (score 0):

When using an optical device, the magnification is the angular size of the final virtual image divided by the angular size of the object as seen by an unaided eye.  To record a real image with film or a charge coupled device, an objective lens (or mirror) with a longer focal length gives a larger image (Consider a pinhole camera).  (A larger aperture gives a brighter and sharper image.)  With a “magnifying glass” (a convex lens), an object inside the focal length gives a larger virtual image at a distance where it can be in focus for the eye.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and maybe unsatisfying answer is that given the laws of refraction (which one may derive from Maxwell's equations), magnification is bound to happen (with the expectation of special cases where the magnification is 1).

If your trace light rays from an object to its image which is formed by a lens (or any arbitrarily complex optical system), you find that rays that originate from two points on the object with some distance X between them will converge into two points on the image with a distance X` which is larger or smaller than X (with the exception of magnification being equal to 1).

[image]